# Mongoose Populate Method is not populating value

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have two mongoose schema as following

```
var ServiceSubType = new Schema({

    displaySubTypeName          : String,
    subTypeDescription          : String,
    status                      : { type: String, default: Constants.ACTIVE },
    lastUpdatedOn               : Date,
    createdOn                   : { type: Date, default: Date.now }

} , { collection: 'SERVICE_SUB_TYPES' });
```

and

```
var ServiceType = new Schema({

    displayName         : String,
    description         : String,
    status              : { type: String, default: Constants.ACTIVE },
    lastUpdatedOn       : Date,
    serviceSubTypeId    : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ServiceSubType', index: true},
    createdBy           : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SystemUser', index: true },
    createdOn           : { type: Date, default: Date.now }

} , { collection: 'SERVICE_TYPES' });
```

I have populated Type Object as below

```
module.exports.addNewServiceType = function(serviceType_obj, callback) {
    serviceType_obj.save(serviceType_obj,callback);
}
```

Now I am trying to populate ServiceSubType document and then at the same time trying to populate "serviceSubTypeId" of ServiceType object referenced to ServiceSubType created.

Here is my piece of code for the same purpose.

```
module.exports.addServiceSubType = function(serviceTypeObjId, serviceSubType_obj, callback) {

    serviceSubType_obj.save(serviceSubType_obj, function (error, serviceSubType) {

    });


    serviceSchema.ServiceType.findById(serviceTypeObjId, function (err, serviceType) {

        var opts = { path: 'serviceSubTypeId'};

        serviceSchema.ServiceType.populate(serviceType, opts, function (err, user) {
            console.log(serviceType);
          });

    }).exec(callback);

}
```

But it is not workign and not populating any value in Existing SubType object.

I admit my approach could be very wrong as I am very new in this technology. Appreciate any kind of help to run this piece of code as expected.

Thanks
Ajoy

Answer (score 0):

I think your `ref` should be the same setting as the `collection` on the object

```
serviceSubTypeId    : {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
  ref: 'SERVICE_SUB_TYPES',  <==== your collection type goes here
  index: true
},
```

Mongoose doesn't know anything about your JavaScript object types. Instead, it tracks things based on the `collection` name that you provide (or that it generates).

**update based on comments below**

I have some example code that I wrote a while back, and it looks like I'm letting Mongoose generate the collection name for me. However, I am supplying a name to the `mogoose.model()` call, when registering my type for a collection.

For example, I have a `Post` type and a `User` type. The Post contains an `author` which is a reference to the User.

It looks like this:

```
// post
// ----

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now},
  title: {type: String, required: true},
  content: {type: String, required: true},
  author: {
    type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    ref: "user"
  },
  comments: [CommentSchema]
});

var Post = mongoose.model("blog", PostSchema);

// user
// ----

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {type: String},
  lastName: {type: String},
  username: {type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true}},
  email: {type: String, required: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true},
  url: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "url"
  }
});

User = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

In this example code, I'm setting the `ref` to "user" because I am registering my model as "user" down below, in the `mongoose.model` method call.

Are you registering your models using mongoose.model and supplying a name? if so, use that name.

Comment: I have tried it ..but it is giving error as                                                                       new MongooseError.MissingSchemaError(name);
          ^
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "SERVICE_SUB_TYPES".

Comment: i updated my answer with some sample code i wrote a while back. hopefully that helps.